# Running out of memory when trying to convert images into numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, memory

I have a list of about 15,000 images which are 120x90 pixels high and wide. I'm trying to convert them into a Numpy array form however when I try to convert them my computer runs out of memory (8GB of ram + 12GB swap). After this is done I'll save to a file for future machine learning training.

```
dataSet = genDataSet()
for image in dataSet:
    pixelImages.append([imageToRGB(image[0], True),image[1]])

def imageToRGB(inputFile, normalise = False):
    os.chdir("/home/spchee/CodeProjects/School Project/images")
    img = Image.open(inputFile) #Opens File
    pixels = np.asarray(img) #Converts it to a numpy array
    pixels = np.rint(pixels)
    if normalise: #This normalises it between the values of 0 and 1
        pixels= pixels/255
    img.close()
    return pixels
```

The function genDataSet() returns a list in the form of [[filepath1, genre], [filepath2, genre]...].

When running this code it runs out of memory so my computer almost totally freezes and I'm forced to force stop it.

Comment: What are you doing with the image that is returned?

Comment: whats the average size of each iimage?

Comment: 15000 images x 120x90 pixels x 4 bytes per pixel = 648000000 bytes = 618MB. I am not sure, but your code may be using 16 bytes per pixel in the end, so it grows to more than to 2GB. That is a lot, but you are probably spending more memory somewhere else. Still, you are anyway on the border of your limits. Change your approach. Don't keep all of the 15000 images in memory at the same time.